# Navigate between fragments from adapter using interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an issue with fragments. In the first fragment I have a recyclerview and when I click to an item, it will get me to another fragment. I defined an interface for that purpose but is not working. Here what I have in my adapter:

```
private List<KategoriteNested> kategoriteNested;
    private Context mContext;

    private static OnItemCLickListener mOnItemCLickListener;

    public void setOnItemCLickListener(OnItemCLickListener onItemCLickListener) {
        mOnItemCLickListener = onItemCLickListener;
    }

    public AllCategoriesAdapter(List<KategoriteNested> kategoriteNested, Context mContext) {
        this.kategoriteNested = kategoriteNested;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AllCategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.all_categories_item, parent, false);
        return new AllCategoriesAdapter.AllCategoriesViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllCategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        KategoriteNested mKategoriteNested = kategoriteNested.get(position);
        String categoryEmertimi = mKategoriteNested.getKategoria().getName();
        holder.categoryEmertimi.setText(categoryEmertimi);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int index = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            mOnItemCLickListener.OnItemClick(index);
        });

    }

    public interface OnItemCLickListener{
        void OnItemClick(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return kategoriteNested.size();
    }

    public static class AllCategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView categoryEmertimi;

        public AllCategoriesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            categoryEmertimi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_emertimi);
        }
    }
```

I get the item position using getAdapterPosition(). And in my fragment I have this:

```
private void goToCategoriesFragment() {
        allCategoriesAdapter = new AllCategoriesAdapter(kategoriteNested, getContext());
        allCategoriesAdapter.setOnItemCLickListener(position -> {
            if (mOnItemCLickListener != null) {
                Fragment fragment = new CategoriesDetailsFragment();
                assert getFragmentManager() != null;
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

I click in the item and nothing is hapenned, I also don't get any error message in the logcat. I wonder if I doing on the right way communication between fragment and adapter using interface, or I'm missing something else. Would someone can give me an explanation how can navigate between fragments using a recyclerview. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make your fragment implement the **`OnItemCLickListener`** interface, also make some changes to your adapter **`constructor`**, so that you pass the list, context and **`OnItemCLickListener`** instance in it. Then make your **`ViewHolders`** implement the same interface and pass that instance you got through the adapter constructor to the viewHolder.

Comment: Can you give me an example?